# More popular place in terms of the flow of people

Tags: single-word-requests

You have 2 places in the city, one place is being passed by more people per day than the other one, meaning that the flow of people in the first one is higher than the flow of people in the second one.

**Question:**

How would you describe this kind of "popularity" of one place in comparison to another?

**Example:**

> The location of their pop-up store in the center was much more **______** than the one in the suburbs, that is why they got rid of the second one.

The words *lucrative* and *profitable* are not suitable for this case.

Thank you!

Comment: [Trafficked](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/trafficked). "It's one of the most trafficked [=the most often visited] sites on the Web."

Comment: ...busier......

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *more busier* ???

Comment: @Mick I inferred that OP essentially required a comparative of suitable form, and would not nit-pick about minor recasting. Quite a reasonable assumption to make, wouldn't you _agree_?

Comment: *frequented*....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! Your answer helped to find the large amount of closely-related words, that I was looking for: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/busy?s=ts

Comment: @PhilSweet Good one!

Answer (score 2):

How about populous? It means having lots of people around.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/populous

Comment: Close. But not exact.

Comment: Ok. How about using 'audience'  'shop a. attracts the largest audience'. Shop a. Has the highest audience. Or say highest number of consumers. Consumer-rich. Has the most customer-rich area (this means, a lot of customers, it does not refer to their pocket value). Highest customer throughput. Hottest retail area. Largest potential audience. Highest amount of customer traffic. High traffic area. Popular shopping area. Shop a. 'Is pumping'.

Comment: Or if you're focused on the relativity, how about 'relatively populous' or 'relatively more populous'.  Eg 'as shop a. is in a relatively more populous area than shop b, it tends to generate more sales'.

Comment: So, 'as the location of their pop-up store in the centre was relatively more populous than the one in the suburbs, they got rid of the second one.'

Comment: Or 'relatively more consumer rich...' sounds rather cool...